# Finding the file system explorer application in a default desktop install?

Tags: filesystem

I'm new to Ubuntu in general (using 10.04) and from the default Ubuntu desktop after a default Ubuntu desktop install, cannot find the file system explorer program in the top application menu.

**UPDATE:** I want to see the **complete**  file system, not just My Documents, My Pics, etc.

I know it's gotta' be there, but maybe I don't recognize the name (because I come from the Windows world) .. so I think this is going to be a race to first post :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually you would want to access the items in the Places menu located to the right of Applications in the top left corner of the screen.

The "Computer" option will give you a view of the removable storage devices on your computer (CD drive, USB drives, etc.) as well as the file system. To get a view of the complete file system go to Places > Computer > File System. This should open a window titles "/ - File Browser" with the full contents of your main file system, which is generally the contents of your hard drive.

For your personal documents and other user files, you can open the "Home Folder" bookmark (usually right at the top of the Places menu) or one of the other bookmarks in that first section.

All of the icons in the first two sections of the Places menu will open the file system explorer in Ubuntu which is called Nautilus although the window will likely be titled "File Browser".

Comment: Ah yes indeed... after I open any place from the "Places" menu, I see on the left side of the window a bookmarklet named "File System" and that gives me everything starting from the root of the system. Cool. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The filesystem browser in Gnome is called Nautilus.